# Prev/Next datatables (jquery plug in) buttons make my page jump to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I use datatables 1.9.4 with datatables-bootstrap3 and every time i click prev/next buttons, my page jump to top. In what could be the problem?

init js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.apptable').dataTable({
      "bFilter": false,
      "bLengthChange": false,
      "sPaginationType": "bs_four_button"
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's only `"sPaginationType": "bs_four_button"` issue and i have it on example page. I open the issue: https://github.com/Jowin/Datatables-Bootstrap3/issues/11